# Delay before cryptsetup password prompt

Tags: boot, cryptsetup

I have an encrypted partition with the system.

During boot, I have a pretty long delay between screen displaying messages and cryptsetup asking me for a password (around 10s)

I can confirm that with `dmesg`

```
[    2.739272] hid-generic 0003:1532:025C.0012: input,hiddev6,hidraw17: USB HID v1.11 Device [Razer Razer BlackWidow V3 Pro] on usb-0000:06:00.3-6.2/input3
[   16.521082] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
```

Ten seconds are waiting for the password prompt, then typing it, then the encryption and finally, it mounts.

Looking at this question and answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029598/xubuntu-18-04-kernel-takes-long-to-boot made me think that it is trying to find SWAP, but I've disabled it `sudo swapoff -a`, commented it out of fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=bce9e3f6-a069-4280-b7fd-901aba6fdd08  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=f68b8c29-141b-4bec-8812-c5203be4f684  /boot  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
UUID=cd4a0015-3306-4c64-988c-83235baca874  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
#/dev/mapper/data-swap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
```

and made sure there is no way to resume:

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=none
sudo update-initramfs -uk all
```

And this is my blkid output:

```
blkid | grep -v squashfs
/dev/mapper/cryptdata: UUID="UFo5le-jPA4-5k4d-fpV3-7eGx-fTGR-6mU5Bo" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/data-root: UUID="cd4a0015-3306-4c64-988c-83235baca874" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="F37A-4778" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="bce9e3f6-a069-4280-b7fd-901aba6fdd08"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="f68b8c29-141b-4bec-8812-c5203be4f684" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8716c6f1-d778-468c-bbb6-9343bd0709ac"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="715ee16e-ba60-487a-8944-23b3b561b2bb" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="6e9352f7-350a-4dd8-80bf-c32df82e4842"
/dev/sda1: UUID="74B2149FB214683E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="22c4e3c1-9133-475b-9717-05ba10c6c1bb"
/dev/sda2: UUID="5410729E10728730" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="494fe213-2eec-4d83-b4c1-c3c5d8d2a6d4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="70928597-313b-4948-a815-bcacaf51a68b"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Backup" UUID="62CC1A35CC1A03C7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a42a242b-bf47-4c0c-a889-c4f7bccb2caf"
/dev/mapper/data-swap: UUID="65e49edd-8a15-4d30-b966-4df0bcdce12f" TYPE="swap"
```

What is the system waiting on before asking me for a password? Can I decrease this time?